# how to call a function returning value in jquery template

Tags: asp.net, jquery-templates

i have a template as below

```
<script id="ActionTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">     
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="#" OnClick="setActionId(${action_id}, ${project_id}, ${merchant_id}, ${channel_id}, ${customer_id})" >${action_id}</a></td> 
    <td>${priority} </td>
    <td>${date_to_display} </td> 
    <td> ${date_from}</td> 
    <td>${action_title} </td>      
    <td> ${status()} (${percentage_completed}%)</td> 
    <td> ${hours}</td> 
    <td>${contactFrom} </td>
    <td>${contactTo} </td> 
  </tr>
</script>
```

in above `${status()}` calls the function status which returns a string like this

```
<script type="language/javascript">
  function status(){
    return "some_string";
  }
</script>
```

my problem is i hav to send a value from template where the status function is called..value like `${action_status}`...

all the values that are in the template like `${priority}`,`${hours}`,etc are binded to template in a pagemethod...

need a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass values from your data to function using the `$data` keyword.  Change the following line in your template like this :

`<td> ${status($data.action_status)} (${percentage_completed}%)</td>`

- assuming 'action_status' is the correct property name from your data...

Update:  Here's the [link to the api](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal).  Look down for the section "Evaluating Expressions and Functions"

Comment: thanx shane that really works..i hav been serching for this since 4 hr ..i m jus starting with templates

Comment: No problem...  The templates are wonderful, aren't they?  Just keep that api link handy... ;)

Comment: yup templates are wonderful..i was gettin confused with the jquery documentation...the api link u gave...its hard for a newbi man like me..i actually gone thru tht once :) ...